# Decimal TryParse

Tags: parsing, decimal

I have a problem with the C# method Decimal.TryParse, working with VS 2012 my code does the following

```
decimal number;
bool isDecimal = Decimal.TryParse("123.1", out number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

and the result as expected was 123.1 printed to the console. However I moved my project to VS 2013 and now the result is 1231, the framework version for both enviroments is .NET 4.5.
I did another test in Ideone.com and the result is 123.1 http://ideone.com/lJY4Vk
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try using `.ToString()` with format you need. i.e n1,n2

Comment: I tried this in Visual Studio 2013 and result is as expected.

Comment: Perhaps there is a setting in visual studio to change this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes visual studio accepts only commas (,) instead of points (.) as a decimal point. Try with commas instead, and if it works, you should change the `CultureInfo` to `InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

if your language is not English then you need to use CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

use this:
bool isDecimal = Decimal.TryParse("123.1",System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ,out numero);